# Paho MQTT loop() and loop_forever() problem

Tags: python-2.7, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mosquitto_actuator.py", line 41, in <module>
    mqttc.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1756, in loop_forever
    rc = self._loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1164, in _loop
    rc = self.loop_read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1556, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2439, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3039, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3087, in _handle_connack
    (flags, result) = struct.unpack("!BB", self._in_packet['packet'])
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
```

```py
# Import package
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Define Variables
MQTT_HOST = "192.168.0.105"
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
MQTT_TOPIC = "Pose"

# Define on connect event function
# We shall subscribe to our Topic in this function
def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc, properties=None):
    mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC, 0)

# Define on_message event function.
# This function will be invoked every time,
# a new message arrives for the subscribed topic
def on_message(mosq, obj, msg, properties=None):
    print(str(msg.payload))

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, properties=None):
    print("Subscribed to topic: " + MQTT_TOPIC)

# Initiate MQTT Client
mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

# Connect with MQTT Broker
mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT)

# Continue monitoring the incoming messages for subscribed topic
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Mosquitto.conf:

```
autosave_interval 1800
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous true
socket_domain ipv4

listener 1883
```

Hi guys, i'm struggling with this error. I am trying to loop for continous listening but the loop doesn't even start. I tried loop(time), loop_start() and loop_stop() but no one is working. Someone can help me?

EDIT: Added the code that cause the error.

EDIT II: Added the mosquitto.conf. I tried with or without "Socket domain ipv4", but it doesen't work.

Comment: Hi @Alessandro Sablone, welcome to Stack Overflow. The error isn't very helpful without the seeing the code that causes it. Please edit the question to include a [minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please include the `mosquitto.conf` file you are using as well

Comment: Added the code that cause the error @romkey

Comment: Added the mosquitto.conf @hardillb